# Clarity on data storage from Google places API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I have been going through the Google Places API and to make optimum use of the API in my app, I need clarity on their Terms of Service regarding Google places API.

My application shows nearby restaurants to a user.
In my database, I have manually collected all the restaurant information such as name, photos, reviews, opening time etc. Please note that this collection has been done manually and not with the Google API.

Now, since Google allows to cache id of places, I have manually mapped their id to my restaurants.So, my database has five fields. id, name, photos, reviews and opening time. Again to reiterate, only the id's are from google, all other data has been manually collected by me.

The reason for doing this is that I want to serve a mix of both info for nearby restaurants. I would always hit Google places API at run time, and along with the information from their api, I would also serve my custom data.

I want to know if this is ok. Google's terms of usage are not very clear, so it would be great if someone can clarify this.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think anyone but Google or maybe lawyers can accurately interpret the ToS for you. You ought to look through the [ToS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) yourself to see if there's anything remotely close that you're doing. If you're just saving Places ID, there should be no problem though.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Any idea about how can I ask Google to answer this. According to google, all questions about Places API have to be asked on stackoverflow. Just wondering how to get clarity on this service terms.

Comment: The only way to ask them directly, that comes to mind, is if you have Google Maps for Work. I believe you can get [Google support](https://developers.google.com/places/support#forwork) with it. They refer to stackoverflow for places api question, but that's probably for code questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues (terms of service), not coding

Comment: @geocodezip I beg to differ here. This is a very crucial question from a developer point of view. Also, Google Places API's official forum is stackoverflow. Hence I highly doubt this question being off-topic. Please review your comment.

Comment: The fact that StackOverflow is Google Places official forum is irrelevant.  That is only true for on topic questions, which in my opinion, this is not. Related question in meta :[Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 5):

This is A-OK! Supporting your use case is actually why we updated the rules recently to make [place IDs exempt from the caching restriction](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/policies#pre-fetching_caching_or_storage_of_content). Just be sure that when you do call Places API to display the place information, you're including the appropriate logo and attribution [requirements](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/policies#logo_requirements).

Comment: Thanks a lot jenharrington !!